# How to use git effectively with TLA+ toolbox

Tags: tla+

The TLA+ toolbox creates a lot of files and directories. What's a good way to work with the spec and the model and keep them versioned in git, and also use the toolbox? What does a normal workflow look like?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to `.gitignore` will only keep the model parameters files, like `MySpec.toolbox/MySpec__Model_1.lauch`, which I found is all I need to restore the model if all other files are lost:

```
# TLA+ Toolbox files, this will keep <spec_name>__<model_name>.launch
/*.toolbox/.settings
/*.toolbox/.project
/*.toolbox/*/*
/*.toolbox/*_SnapShot_*.launch
# TLA+ Toolbox PDF production artifacts
/*.toolbox/*.aux
/*.toolbox/*.log
/*.toolbox/*.tex
/*.toolbox/*.pdf
/*.pdf
```

You can verify that it is enough with those steps:

- commit `MySpec.toolbox/MySpec__Model_1.lauch`
- close the spec in the toolbox (if you don't the toolbox will show an error that you can dismiss next time you open it)
- quit the toolbox
- delete everything in `MySpec.toolbox/` except `MySpec__Model_1.lauch`
- reopen the toolbox
- reopen your spec with `Add New Spec...`
- recreate a model with the same name as before, `Model_1` in this example
- save and close the model
- quit the toolbox
- drop the changes made to `MySpec.toolbox/MySpec__Model_1.lauch` by the toolbox when saving the model
- reopen the toolbox

The only downside for now is that there is parameter call `fpIndex` stored in `MySpec.toolbox/MySpec__Model_1.lauch` which changes at each model execution, see **Fingerprint seed index** in https://tla.msr-inria.inria.fr/tlatoolbox/doc/model/tlc-options-page.html. This causes this file to appear in the changed files in git everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I have completely ignored `*.toolbox` in my `.gitignore`. This means model configuration is not preserved in the repo which is not ideal.

A good workflow is possible with the VS Code plugin that relies on top-level `.cfg` files configuring model constants and which invariants/properties to check.

This is my `.gitignore`

```
*.dvi
*.old
*.out
*.pdf
*.tex
*.toolbox
```

I keep a `Makefile` with useful tasks like cleaning up these auxiliary files and maintaining pretty-printed PDFs in a separate `dist/` folder.

```
JAVA ?= java
TLA2TOOLS_JAR = "tla2tools.jar"
TLA2TOOLS ?= $(JAVA) --class-path $(TLA2TOOLS_JAR)
TLA2TEX ?= $(JAVA) --class-path ../$(TLA2TOOLS_JAR) \
                                           tla2tex.TLA -latexCommand "pdflatex" -shade -grayLevel 0.9

DISTDIR = dist
PDFS = $(addprefix $(DISTDIR)/, $(patsubst %.tla, %.pdf, $(wildcard *.tla)))

all: dist

pdfs: $(PDFS)

$(DISTDIR)/%.pdf: %.tla
        cd $(DISTDIR) && $(TLA2TEX) ../$^

dist: pdfs clean

clean:
        @echo "Cleaning auxiliary TLA2TeX files"
        @rm -f $(DISTDIR)/*.aux $(DISTDIR)/*.dvi $(DISTDIR)/*.log $(DISTDIR)/*.tex

distclean: clean
        rm -f $(DISTDIR)/*.pdf

.PHONY: pdfs dist clean distclean
```